# 3 Table Laravel Migration need advice

Tags: laravel, migration, relationship

I think I am doing this correctly.  I have a users, profile, and application table.  Below are the migrations.  I think I am linking them correctly in the migration but need advice to make sure.  1 user can have 1 profile but many applications.

**User Table**

```
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

**Profile Table**

```
       public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('apt')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->string('zipcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('homephone')->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile')->nullable();
            $table->string('occupation')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('over18')->nullable();
            $table->string('homechurch')->nullable();
            $table->string('homechurchcity')->nullable();
            $table->string('pastor')->nullable();
            $table->string('howoftenattend')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

**Application**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pilgrim_application', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('besttimetocall');
            $table->string('nickname');
            
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('profile_id')->constrained('profile')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your migration work at the moment?

First check your migration file order, for example

0000_user

0001_profile

1000_ pilgrim_application

1001_app_two

in case of multiple applications you could begin the migration with a different number for grouping files in a list, this can be handy if you want to create multiple applications.

Also, is it necessary to specify the relations user and profile in the pilgrim_application migration?

Through relationships in your models you can also access the pilgrim_application from the user model and vice versa.

```
$user->profile->pilgrim_application
```